# Last item of vector not displaying/vector indexing issue

Tags: c++, boost, vector, cout, boost-graph

I have a weird bug that I simply cannot find.

I am building an adjacency_list graph using the Boost Graph Library, and am populating a list of vertices into a vector. When I iterate through the vector, it will print out all of the vertices correctly, however, when I am running algorithms, such as Dijkstra's Shortest Path, the *last* vertex is displaying blank.

For example:

```
Shortest path from C to R 
C -> H = 55 
H ->  = 97
  -> R = 56

Distance: 208
```

To make things worse, If I write a simple search to select a particular vertex, the *last* vertex in the vector is once again a problem, as it suggests that it is not there.

```
std::string start_vertex;
bool valid = false;
std::cout << "Vertices:" << std::endl;
for (auto &i : _vertices) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
while (!valid) {
    std::cout << "Enter starting vertex: ";
    std::cin >> start_vertex;
    for (auto &i : _vertices) {
        if (i == start_vertex) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above, when searching for the problem vertex, continues the loop, while all other vertices work correctly. As mentioned earlier, the vertices all print out when iterated through otherwise.

Finally, when the above foreach loop runs, the *first* vertex is blank. I imagine all of these are related, but I cannot figure out what I have done here. I am happy to provide more code, but it would be helpful to get a sense of what I should be looking for first.

Thanks.

---

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main(int , const char * argv[]) {
    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    typedef int Weight;
    typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string> VertexNameProperty;
    typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, Weight> EdgeWeightProperty;
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                                                                VertexNameProperty, EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
    typedef boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_index_t>::type IndexMap;
    typedef boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_name_t>::type NameMap;
    typedef boost::iterator_property_map<Vertex*, IndexMap, Vertex, Vertex&>
    PredecessorMap;
    typedef boost::iterator_property_map<Weight*, IndexMap, Weight, Weight&>
    DistanceMap;
    std::string line, vertex;
    std::getline(input, line);
    std::getline(input, line);
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(",");
    typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
    tokenizer tok(line, sep);
    std::vector<std::string> _vertices;
    for (auto &i : tok) {
        _vertices.push_back(i);
    }
    Graph g(sizeof(_vertices));
    std::map<std::string, Vertex> vertex_map;
    for (auto &i : _vertices) {
        vertex_map[i] = boost::add_vertex(std::string(i), g);
    }
    char c;
    struct GraphParameters {
        char vertex_one, vertex_two;
        Weight edge_weight;
    };
    std::getline(input, line);
    while (getline(input, line)) {
        GraphParameters p;
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> c >> p.vertex_one >> c >> p.vertex_two >> c >> p.edge_weight >> c;
        std::string v1, v2;
        std::stringstream ss1 ,ss2;
        ss1 << p.vertex_one;
        ss1 >> v1;
        ss2 << p.vertex_two;
        ss2 >> v2;
        boost::add_edge(vertex_map[v1], vertex_map[v2], p.edge_weight, g);
    }
std::string start_vertex, end_vertex;
bool valid = false;
std::cout << "Vertices:" << std::endl;
for (auto &i : _vertices) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
while (!valid) {
    std::cout << "Enter starting vertex: ";
    std::cin >> start_vertex;
    for (auto &i : _vertices) {
        if (i == start_vertex) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
  }
}
while (valid) {
    std::cout << "Enter ending vertex: ";
    std::cin >> end_vertex;
    for (auto &i : _vertices) {
        if (i == end_vertex) {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
    std::vector<Vertex> predecessors(boost::num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<Weight> distances(boost::num_vertices(g));
    IndexMap indexMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    PredecessorMap predecessorMap(&predecessors[0], indexMap);
    DistanceMap distanceMap(&distances[0], indexMap);
    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, vertex_map[start_vertex],
                                                                 boost::distance_map(distanceMap)
                                                                 .predecessor_map(predecessorMap));
    NameMap nameMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    typedef std::vector<Graph::edge_descriptor> PathType;
    PathType path;
    Vertex v = vertex_map[end_vertex];
    for(Vertex u = predecessorMap[v]; u != v; v = u, u = predecessorMap[v]) {
        std::pair<Graph::edge_descriptor, bool> edgePair = boost::edge(u, v, g);
        Graph::edge_descriptor edge = edgePair.first;
        path.push_back(edge);
    }
    std::cout << "Shortest path from " << start_vertex << " to " << end_vertex
                        << std::endl;
    for(PathType::reverse_iterator pathIterator = path.rbegin(); pathIterator
            != path.rend(); ++pathIterator) {
        std::cout << nameMap[boost::source(*pathIterator, g)] << " -> "
                            << nameMap[boost::target(*pathIterator, g)]
                            << " = " << boost::get(boost::edge_weight, g, *pathIterator)
                            << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Distance: " << distanceMap[vertex_map[end_vertex]] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::end;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

An example input file:

```
Vertices:
S,H,R,C,G
Edges
(S,C,39)
(R,S,86)
(G,S,74)
(C,H,55)
(R,C,126)
(G,C,68)
(R,H,111)
(G,R,56)
(H,G,97)
(S,H,27)
```

Comment: Does this happen with any number of vertices?  Have you tried removing/adding one to the collections you test?

Comment: Yes. If I add, it just pushes the error back.

Comment: Okay, let's see some populate and print snippets.  Ideally, as a MCVE that can be compiled w/ a linked boost library

Comment: Probably related to the way you put items into the vector. You must show that code as well

Comment: MCVE is your friend. Start with one.

Comment: Added. Let me know if there are any issues as I quickly converted that to a main method

Comment: Does the issue come up if you populate the vector directly?

Comment: When you use `Graph g(n);` and then call `add_vertex` n times you end up with a graph with 2*n vertices (n of them default initialized). Additionally `sizeof(vertices)` is not the same as `vertices.size()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Graph g(sizeof(_vertices));
```

That's a bug. You wanted to write.

```
Graph g(_vertices.size());
```

However, that's still wrong. You are already adding vertices in the loop later (`add_vertex`) so you don't need to pre-populate the graph.

```
Graph g;
```

### Working Demo

The below program has some style fixes (allowing me to *read* the code, as well as rely on the parsing a bit more) and I tested it exhaustively with all possible valid inputs:

```
for i in {S,H,R,C,G}\ {S,H,R,C,G}; do valgrind ./test <<< $i; done
```

(Which is the same as http://paste.ubuntu.com/14002530/)

It shows all runs complete cleanly without detectable memory errors.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14002549/)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace {
    typedef int Weight;
    typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string> VertexNameProperty;
    typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, Weight> EdgeWeightProperty;
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexNameProperty, EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
    typedef boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_index_t>::type IndexMap;
    typedef boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_name_t>::type NameMap;
    typedef boost::iterator_property_map<Vertex*, IndexMap, Vertex, Vertex&> PredecessorMap;
    typedef boost::iterator_property_map<Weight*, IndexMap, Weight, Weight&> DistanceMap;
}

template <typename V, typename VM>
Graph readGraph(std::string const& fname, V& _vertices, VM& vertex_map) {
    std::ifstream input(fname);
    std::string line, vertex;
    std::getline(input, line);
    assert(line == "Vertices:");

    std::getline(input, line);
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(",");
    typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
    tokenizer tok(line, sep);

    for (auto &i : tok) {
        _vertices.insert(_vertices.end(), i);
    }

    Graph g;
    for (auto &i : _vertices) {
        vertex_map[i] = boost::add_vertex(std::string(i), g);
    }

    char c;
    struct GraphParameters {
        char source, target;
        Weight weight;
    };

    std::getline(input, line);
    assert(line == "Edges");

    while (getline(input, line)) {
        GraphParameters p;
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> c && c == '('
                && iss >> p.source >> c && c == ','
                && iss >> p.target >> c && c == ','
                && iss >> p.weight >> c && c == ')') 
        {
            boost::add_edge(
                    vertex_map[std::string(1,p.source)],
                    vertex_map[std::string(1,p.target)],
                    p.weight,
                    g);
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("Parse error in '" + line + "'\n");
        }
    }

    return g;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string>      _vertices;
    std::map<std::string, Vertex> vertex_map;
    auto g = readGraph("input.txt", _vertices, vertex_map);

    std::string start_vertex, end_vertex;
    bool valid = false;
    std::cout << "Vertices:" << std::endl;
    for (auto &i : _vertices) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    while (!valid) {
        std::cout << "Enter starting vertex: ";
        std::cin >> start_vertex;
        for (auto &i : _vertices) {
            if (i == start_vertex) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (valid) {
        std::cout << "Enter ending vertex: ";
        std::cin >> end_vertex;
        for (auto &i : _vertices) {
            if (i == end_vertex) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    std::vector<Vertex> predecessors(boost::num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<Weight> distances(boost::num_vertices(g));

    IndexMap indexMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    PredecessorMap predecessorMap(&predecessors[0], indexMap);
    DistanceMap distanceMap(&distances[0], indexMap);

    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, vertex_map[start_vertex],
                                   boost::distance_map(distanceMap).predecessor_map(predecessorMap));

    NameMap nameMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    typedef std::vector<Graph::edge_descriptor> PathType;

    PathType path;
    Vertex v = vertex_map[end_vertex];
    for (Vertex u = predecessorMap[v]; u != v; v = u, u = predecessorMap[v]) {
        std::pair<Graph::edge_descriptor, bool> edgePair = boost::edge(u, v, g);
        Graph::edge_descriptor edge = edgePair.first;
        path.push_back(edge);
    }
    std::cout << "Shortest path from " << start_vertex << " to " << end_vertex << std::endl;
    for (PathType::reverse_iterator pathIterator = path.rbegin(); pathIterator != path.rend(); ++pathIterator) {
        std::cout << nameMap[boost::source(*pathIterator, g)] << " -> " << nameMap[boost::target(*pathIterator, g)]
                  << " = " << boost::get(boost::edge_weight, g, *pathIterator) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Distance: " << distanceMap[vertex_map[end_vertex]] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think he needs `Graph g;`.

Comment: @cv_and_he Indeed. Completed the testing. Recorded livestream is [here](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/review-dijkstra-code-sample/).

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: Cheers :) More cleanup in [session part #2](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/review-dijkstra-code-sample-part-2/): http://paste.ubuntu.com/14002676/ (separation of concerns, code reuse, simplified property usage)

Comment: Interestingly enough, compiled as is, the issue is still present. Which is odd because I saw that it displayed for you...

Comment: you need to eliminate sources of error. Try a different machine, a separate project, different user, full rebuild, insert deliberate `#error` to see whether it's compiling the right stuff, add breakpoints. If all that doesn't remove the problem, show your **exact** code **and** data.